# flash error "Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: images.xml"

Tags: flash

I am working on a ASP website, which everything seems fine, but when i implement a slider on a page inside a folder in the root (i.e. aboutus/index.aspx) i get that error when the slider is trying to call the images.

I have similar slider animations in pages located in the root folder and in those i get no problem at all, seems it only happens when the page is located inside a folder.

The website is done using main.master on asp, maybe the cache or rendering of the website is missing something, hope someone has had something similar or know how to get around this.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your SWF located  - root or somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

You need to consider where the swf is and where the html is. I think the path to the xml is relative to the html. Also the error you are getting is unhandled ioerror. The actionscript should have a handler to handle this so that you can debug it by tracing it out or writing to a logger.

eg:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
```

and then handle the error in a function

```
function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
    // debug here or do some fallback operation
}
```

check out this link see if it helps:

http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=782174

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, although my video player is not loading any xml nor images. Everything was working fine on last session, and suddenly this message started to pop up. I set an ioErrorEvent handler at the root of the application. It worked but the funny thing was that the handler never showed signs of any event trace statement.

At the constructor of the root class:

```
this.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.errorHandler );

//wrote this function
private function errorHandler( event:ErrorEvent ):void
{
    trace( "got you.!!! " + event.toString() );
}
```

Comment: the handler should be on a loader not the root class